# prettyphoto add delay

Tags: jquery

I have currently installed prettyphoto and managed to launch an iframe on page load through

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

What is the quickest way to add a delay to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function in javascript is easy to use.

You probably do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#photo').prettyphoto(); //Not sure how you call prettyphoto
}
```

Add a delay before you make your call :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //The call to callPrettyPhoto will only be made after 1 second
    window.setTimeout(callPrettyPhoto, 1000 );
});

function callPrettyPhoto() {
    $('#photo').prettyphoto();
}
```

Note that you can also put the function inline if you wish to do so :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('#photo').prettyphoto();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much Mr. Migneron - outstanding, can't thank you enough :)